# How to install a patch for dig

Tags: linux, diff, patch, dig

I have a .diff edns-client-ip patch file for dig, but i dont know how to install it. Any tips?
The patch for it is available here-
http://wilmer.gaa.st/edns-client-subnet/

Answer (score 0):

try `patch` in the source directory of bind-dig-edns

```
$ cd /path/to/bind-xxx-dig-edns-client/src
$ patch -p1 < bind-xxx-dig-edns-client-subnet.diff
```